# NSFetchedResultsController adds duplicate section to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` which fetches objects from `CoreData` and updates a `UICollectionView` for displaying the data accordingly. The data in the `UICollectionView` is organised in sections based on a property from a `CoreData` relationship. This relationship looks like the following

```
// an Item belongs to exactly one Category - a Category can host multiple Items
Item <<---> Category
```

Once I add a new `Item` with a `Category` thats already in the database a new section is added to the `UICollectionView`, but thats just for the first new `Item` - every new `Item` added later gets inserted in this new section. The new section doesn't show up in the `sqlite` database, just in the `UICollectionView` managed by `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I use the following code to insert a new item

```
let newItem = Item(context: managedObjectContext)
...
let request: NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "categoryA")

do {
    let searchResults = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
    newItem.category = searchResults.first  
} catch {
    print("Error with request: \(error)")
}
```

Once I close the app and relaunch it, the new section disappears and all the `Items` are located in the correct sections - probably something wrong with the `NSFetchedResultsController`, so here is the important code.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.insert {
        blockOperations.append(
            BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                if let this = self {
                    this.collectionView!.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex) as IndexSet)
                    
                }
                })
        )
    }
    else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update {
        blockOperations.append(
            BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                if let this = self {
                    this.collectionView!.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex) as IndexSet)
                }
                
                })
        )
    }
    else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.delete {
        blockOperations.append(
            BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                if let this = self {
                    this.collectionView!.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex) as IndexSet)
                } 
                })
        )
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the `UICollectionView` after a new `Item` is added to `CoreData`
[image: Screenshot]

---

**EDIT:**

I use this code to instantiate NSFetchedResultsController

```
    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Item>? = nil

var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Item> {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
    
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    let managedObjectContext = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.getContext()
    
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "completed != true")

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "category", ascending: true)]
    let resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath:"category", cacheName: nil)
    
    resultsController.delegate = self;
    _fetchedResultsController = resultsController
    
    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror)")
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you instantiate the ```NSFetchedResultsController``` and begin its fetching?

Comment: I updated the question with the instantion method of NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: Not that this should make a difference, but out of curiosity what happens if you set the delegate after calling performFetch (instead of setting it before).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, unfortunately setting the delegate after performFetch makes no difference

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?